# Using concat() to build a column alias name

Tags: mariadb, string-concatenation

I am using `concat()` to create the name for a column name:

```
set @var = 10;
select col as concat("str1", cast(@var as CHAR), "str2") from table1;
```

But I get the following syntax error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ('str1', cast(@var as char), 'str2')

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: I got the following syntax error
"1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ('str1', cast(@var as char), 'str2')"

Comment: Do you want to get: `select col as str110str2 from table1;`?

Comment: @wchiquito yes, but I don't know how to write it in a valid way.

Comment: The alias field of a statement cannot be constructed by any string manipulation function.  Do it in your application code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SET @var := 10;

SET @`sql` := CONCAT('select col as ',
                     'str1', cast(@var as CHAR), 'str2',
                     ' from table1');

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`sql`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

Comment: A little more explanation would be helpful. What's the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: @RickJames: It's not necessary to do so within a stored procedure, it can be done from MySQL Command-Line.